# How to disable libreoffice impress autorecovery over ssh

Tags: ssh, debian, raspberry-pi, libreoffice

Is there a way to tell libreoffice impress to skip autorecovery of files when you have no access to the machine it runs on despite ssh?

Another way of asking would be: Is it possible to completely control X or an application running in it via ssh?

This is about an RPi running in Kiosk mode without any input devices connected.
Thank you so much for any advice on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable autorecovery by **starting LibreOffice with the command line option**

```
--norestore
```

For example:

```
libreoffice --norestore --impress
```

Disabling saving of autorestore information (`Tools` -> `Options` -> `Load/Save` -> `General` -> `Save AutoRecovery Information every ... Minutes`) won't disable the Autorecovery mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) to control the desktop even if you would sit in front of it. The simplest setup would be:

```
user@raspy apt-get install tightvncserver
user@raspy tightvncserver # start it
```

Then connect using a vnc viewer to port 5901

---

You could also connect via `ssh -X` to redirect x traffic to the local x server. Try:

```
ssh -X raspbian_machine
gnome-text-editor
```

It will open the text editor on your local machine.